# How To Write XML to applicationDirectory for android air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to write an xml file to my applicationDirectory, but it doesnt work...

My code is:

```
pathToFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("app:/tbHewan.xml").nativePath;//   
file = new File(pathToFile);
fileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes(xml.toXMLString());
hais.text = file.nativePath+"\n"+file.url; //this only for tracing my location
fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileClosed);
fileStream.close();
```

But it doesnt work on my android device

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to `File.applicationDirectory` (or use `app:` which is just a URL shortcut to `File.applicationDirectory`). It is a protected path in android [and it is considered bad practice in all OS versions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationDirectory), use `File.applicationStorageDirectory` instead.

```
pathToFile = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("tbHewan.xml").nativePath;
```